# Choosing images size when uploading

Tags: uploads, media-library

Is there a way to choose which image size I want to resize to when uploading?

I need one image type to be for a featured image (resizing would be for thumbnail size and 900x350) and the other type for a  gallery (resizing each image for thumbnail size and 640x480).
So when I want to upload an image i get to choose which type i want to work with.

I have read about registering image sizes in Wp codex and thats all clear just that I dont know how to put selections for it during upload.

Couldnt find any plugin either that would do this.

Any information no matter how small is really welcomed

Answer (score 0):

For trivia WP will generate *all* registered sizes for *every* image natively. While this doesn't quite seem optimal, the recommendation (if one might call it that) to deal with it is "get bigger disks". :) If size isn't a concern you can just go with it.

The typical solution takes a little different angle. Instead of generating specific sizes on upload, the sizes are generated when they are first requested. So the specific combinations of image and size which are never requested are never created.

There are several implementation like that around, but I hadn't used any recently to recommend specific one. You might get better luck searching for keyword of "thumbnails" rather than "sizes".